# Extending K&R's rand() into 64-bits?

Tags: c, random

Is there a straight-forward way to extend this rand() function (from K&R's "The C Programming Language") to yield 64 random bits instead of 15?

```
int rand()
{
  rand_next = rand_next * 1103515245 + 12345;
  return (unsigned int)(rand_next/ 65536) % 32768;
}
```

EDIT: And what I mean by that is changing it to use 64-bit numbers and different magic numbers.  As opposed to throwing this in a for loop.

EDIT #2: This algorithm is effectively 15 bits of randomness, not 30.  Stupid math mistake in my original post.

Comment: Just call it multiple times and do some bit-wise magic?

Comment: "Numerical Recipes In C" had a list of appropriate numbers for Linear Congruential  RNGs.

Comment: Don't. There are by far better (and at least as fast) alternative PRNGs around (and easily available). See [GSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Scientific_Library) for example.

Comment: Also don't call the normal `rand` multiple times and join the results. You can *only* lose entropy by doing that (unless of course the joining uses some other entropy source with higher entropy, in which case, you should just stick with that by itself.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linear congruential generators exist for any number of bits.

For 64 bits, MMIX (for example) uses the following recursive formula:

```
x = x * 6364136223846793005 + 1442695040888963407;
```

Answer (score 0):

PRNG's require special numbers to work. There are a few listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). One of them is 64 bits.

```
n = (n * 6364136223846793005 + 1442695040888963407) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
```

or

```
n = (n * 0x5d588b656c078965 + 0x269ec3) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
```

There are other types of PRNG but I believe the LCRNG (Linear Congruential) is the easiest.